# Implementing a database table to record two way user following system

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

The two tables here are :

user_table
--user_id (int)
--user_name (int)
--user_profile_link (varchar(max))
--user_joined_date (smalldatetime)
--user_thumbnail_pic (varbinary(MAX))

follower_table
--follow_id
--followed_user_id ( who i am following )
--following_user_id ( who i am )
--followed_mutual ( default : NO ) -- to identify if both are following each other

is this approach correct ? or do i need something else to make this tick ! need some advice on this guys...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I (personally) would create separate one-way relationships. If user 12 follows user 37 and it's mutual, then `follower_table` will have two records

```
user   following
  12       37
  37       12
```

Also, I would go ahead and duplicate reverse relationships

```
user   followed_by
  37       12
  12       37
```

This makes queries easier, and also greatly simplifies sharding of data, should you ever need to split your data across multiple DB servers.

Comment: I like this approach, i think it would be much faster to query this...thanks

Answer (score 1):

The follower table is a many to many table. So you dont need to have this field followed_mutual ( default : NO ) , since effectively you can query this table by doing a self join to find if they are mutual followers.
I would also suggest that the user thumbnail field user_thumbnail_pic (varbinary(MAX)) in the usertable be put in a seperate table so that your queries are faster and that way it wont involve in queries that are more frequent.

Comment: thanks lloydom, I would remove that field. the images are actually on a separate table and here i have just put it there for simplicity..